# Google Chrome Java/netty.io

Tags: java, google-chrome

Посредством netty поднял сервер, при попытке выполнить запрос через хром, открывается ДВА канала с разных портов. Firefox, Explorer, Telnet отрабатывают ок, с одним соединением на один запрос.
Сервер:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

    try {
        ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
        b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
                .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
                        ChannelPipeline p = socketChannel.pipeline();
                        p.addLast("codec", new HttpServerCodec());
                        p.addLast("handler", new ReceivedRequestHandler());
                    }
                });
        b.bind(PORT).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } finally {
        bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
```

Лог:
[image: лог]

Это связано с внутренней работой хрома, плагинами или я рукожопый?

Answer (score 1):

Наткнулся на ответ:

> I had a similar issue with my node server. It is due to the following bug in Chrome. In summary, Chrome is sending a request for a favicon on every request. As, is likely, you aren't sending a favicon back, it requests one after every legitimate request.
>
> Firefox, and most other browsers, also send out a request for a favicon when they first connect, but cache the result i.e. if there isn't a favicon returned first time, they don't keep trying - which is why you're only seeing a single request from Firefox. It seems Chrome is unfortunately a little too persistent with its favicon requestiness.

Интересная особенность)

Answer (score 0):

Это связанно только с работой хрома и плагинами. По крайней мере в Вашем коде все нормально.